# Could not access controls in codebehind page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I declared Linkbutton control in Gridview but in code behind i could not access that. Below is my aspx page code.

```
<%@ Page="" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/MainMaster.Master"
    CodeBehind="Page.aspx.cs" Inherits="IntakeLibrary.Page" %>
  <%@ Register="" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
        <contenttemplate>
          <asp:GridView ID="grdView" runat="server">
            <Columns>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Text">
                <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>
        </contenttemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Content>
```

Below is my codebehind code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    LinkButton1.Text = "Test";
}
```

Below is the error i am getting

> **The name 'LinkButton1' does not exist in the current context**

Comment: you should try to use or implement the findcontrols method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a `LinkButton` on your page - you have a `LinkButton` in the `ItemTemplate` in one column of a `GridView` in the template of your `UpdatePanel`. You'll need to reach down past all those layers before you'll be able to reference the `LinkButton` itself.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong method, the correct way is to assign the text in the button control tag itself. This button is inside a gridview so it will be repeated. You cannot reference suppose 10 rendered buttons with one property right? You have to loop through and change their text on row data bound event.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to use a DataGrid_RowDataBound event handler and get a handle to the control in the correct template type and then on the item passed into the event handler do a find control on the link button.  I'll get a code example up shortly.